# Spotfire table visualisation wrap text, iterate over multiple vis with same name and get vertical scroll to be smooth

Tags: python, formatting, ironpython, spotfire

So far, we are using a single cell from a table to house commentary for a Spotfire dashboard.  To date, the first request was to wrap the text dependent on visualisation size (as rendered by the screen size) in which I put together the below code.

```
from System import Guid
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot


cols = None
for vis in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
if vis.Title == 'Commentary':
    tablePlot = vis.As[TablePlot]()
    cols = tablePlot.TableColumns
visualBounds=Document.ActivePageReference.GetVisualBounds(vis)
print cols.Count

for col in cols:
    print col.Name
    col.Width = visualBounds.Width - 20
tablePlot.WrapCellText = True
fitToWindow=Document.Pages.VisualizationAreaSize.FitToWindow
```

Now I need to modify the code to allow for smooth vertical scrolling as the current scrolling just flicks from a wrapped version to nothing as I believe Spotfire believes the tablevis has now shown what it was asked. I have worked my way slowly to create this piece of IronPython code, but have not been able to get any further. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.
LW

Answer (score 1):

it's a little hard to say without any kind of visual, but it sounds like you're trying to use a Table visualization to display regular text?

if this text does not need to relate to another cell in a row, you can display it in a Text Area using a Calculated Value. you can then wrap the Calculated Value in HTML with some CSS for styling and to influence its layout. it will automatically wrap to whatever the container is just as in a web browser.

1. create a new Text Area
2. right click the new Text Area and Edit HTML
3. click Insert Dynamic Item (the up/down arrows) and choose Calculated Value
4. set up the Data page to point to your Data Table. on the Values page, use `First([MyTextColumn])`
5. back in the HTML editor, surround your new `<Spotfire.../>` element with a `<div style="xxx">` where `xxx` is the CSS you want to apply to this text.

Comment: Hi niko - appreciate the feedback.

I ended up going down the Calculated Value avenue and using simple HTML/CSS to make it wrap and scroll. 

The person I was helping was very thankful. Appreciate your response.